# .Attachments.Add on the file that is running the code

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, email-attachments, onedrive

I've code that has been working for over a year that has stopped working.

When I try to add the current file as an attachment to an Outlook email it throws an error saying that the file is already open or I don't have permission to access it.

> Run-Time error '-2147024864 (80070020')

-If I attach the same file (so the file being attached is closed) from a different macro it works, showing (I believe) that it isn't a permission issue.

-The file is located in my OneDrive folder. If I pull it out on the desktop it works. Points to OneDrive being the issue.

-If I create a new file, save it in the OneDrive folder and paste the below code into a module it works. If I then close the file and reopen it, the issue returns.

-I have over 10 computers that have this issue that are on Excel Build 9001.2144.
I have one computer (same model computer as some that aren't working) that is on Build 8730.2127 that doesn't have the issue. All computers have the same OneDrive build, 17.3.7294.0108.

-I took one computer that wasn't working and reverted to Build 8730.2127 and it worked. Seems something changed in the update related to how OneDrive and Excel are interacting.

The problem line is:

```
.Attachments.Add ThisWorkbook.FullName
```

In my research it seems that attaching the active file/active workbook is common.

```vb
Dim OutApp As Object, OutMail As Object

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
With OutMail
    .To = ""
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = ""
    .Body = ""
    .Attachments.Add ThisWorkbook.FullName
    .Display
End With

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
```

Comment: I tried the code you posted and it worked OK for me. Can you post the exact error message you are getting?

Comment: Run-Time error '-2147024864 (80070020':

Comment: Can't open file. It's possible the file is already open, or you don't have permission to open it.

Comment: Where is the code located?

Comment: In a module, activated by a button on the file I'm trying to attach. The code will do a few minor changes to the file, resave it, then email it. I tried skipping all the code but what I posted and the issue remains. Also tried adding a brand new button with just the code above same result.

Comment: Maybe save a copy of the file and attach the copy?

Comment: Good thought. I bet that would work and I'll probably start writing the code tomorrow to do just that. Only issue with that fix is I have over 150 files in the system that will take months to flush through with this faulty code (or a lot of time updating each one individually. I have multiple modules that use a variation of this function as well that aren't working either.) On top of that, for prides sake (8 hours working on this already) I want a fix! haha